# Jquery How to remove everything from text area after the fifth comma?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I'm looking for a way to remove all the text in a textarea **after** the fifth comma, by Jquery.

I have some basic knowledge about Jquery, but I don't know how to do this.

For example if the text is: 
*one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight*

I want the new text in the textarea to be: *one,two,three,four,five,*

The html textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="questionone" id="questionone"></textarea>
```

Comment: You don't need jquery for this. jquery is for dom manipulation and whatnot. It doesn't add much of anything for fancy string manipulation. that's "just" javascript.

Comment: `value.split(',', 5).join(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you can do is split the entire input string (textarea content) by the comma character:

```
var text_arr = textarea_content.split( "," );
```

You can even give an additional parameter to the `split` function to tell it to take only the first X elements: `textarea_content.split( ",", 5 );`.

Now all that is left is to build the string again and separate each element with a comma:

```
var shorter_string = text_arr.join( "," );
```

Here is a simple example:

```
var str = "this,is,some,long,text,that,needs,to,be,truncated";
var text_arr = str.split( ",", 5 );
var shorter_string = text_arr.join( "," ); // "this,is,some,long,text"
```

To combine these statements into one command would be easy:

```
var str = "this,is,some,long,text,that,needs,to,be,truncated";
var shorter_string = str.split( ",", 5 ).join( "," );
```

Reference:

- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: The slice part can be skipped by passing a limit to `split` (as in my comment).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - ahh.. you are correct! I've made an edit to reflect that. Thanks for the feedback!